# Jest fail to spy in object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

We had a disturbing error while using Jest for our unit test.

**The problem**: *Jest* do not access to the inner object method

**The case**: there's a `lol` object with a and `b()` method, if we call the b method directly, *Jest* fail, if we call it with `lol.b()` it works

Did someone already have encountered this problem? Is there a better workaround?

**The code:**

```
describe('Jest bug', () => {    
    it('Jest fail', () => {
        const lol = (() => {
            const a = () => {
                console.log("console a");
                b();
            };
            const b = () => {
                console.log("console b");
            };
            return {
                a,
                b
            };
        })();

        const spy = jest.spyOn(lol, 'b');

        lol.a();

        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    });

    it('Jest success', () => {
        const lol = (() => {
            const a = () => {
                console.log("console OK a");
                lol.b();
            };
            const b = () => {
                console.log("console OK b");
            };
            return {
                a,
                b
            };
        })();

        const spy = jest.spyOn(lol, 'b');

        lol.a();

        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Jest `spyOn` internally replaces object method whith spy function - the spy function is 'attached' to object, it doesn't wrap original function to which object property points.  If you set spy on `lol.b` method Jest does something like this (of course below code is huge simplification and is just to show general idea):

```
let b = function() {
  ...
}; 

let lol = {
    b: b
};

spyOn(lol, 'b');
//Jest internally does something like this
lol.b = function jestSpyFunction() {
   ...
};
```

So if you now call `b()` directly Jest spy is totally not aware of this because `jestSpyFunction` is not called in such case - it will be called only if you use `lol.b()`.
So in my opintion your second implementaion of `lol` is correct and it should be done this way to make code testable. Besides, you define `a` and `b` functions as 'private' (inside anonymous function) so it's correct and intended behaviour that they're not accessible from the outer scope (even by Jest spies).

Comment: This is not an object method, it is a property